# kth smallest number using variation of quicksort

Tags: c, sorting, debugging

I have the following partition method and kthsmallest method (Variation of quicksort) which works for some cases but gives me the value 32767 for a few cases.

```
void swap(int* a, int* b){

int temp = *b;
*b = *a;
*a = temp;
}

int partition(int* arr, int l, int r){

int pivot = arr[r];
int i = l, j=0;

for(j=l; j<=r-1; j++){
    if(arr[j] <= pivot){
        swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        i++;
    }
}

swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
return i;
}
```

And the kthsmallest function is as follows:-

```
int kthsmallest(int* arr, int low, int high, int k){
 /* low = 0 and high = #elements - 1 */
 /* k is in between 1 to high + 1 */

 if (k>0 & k<=high-low+1)     {
    // pos is partitioning index, arr[p] is now  at right place
    int pos = partition(arr, low, high);

    // Separately sort elements before / partition and after partition

    if(pos-low == k-1){
            return arr[pos];
    }
    //if position returned is greater than k, recurse left subarray
    else if(pos-low > k-1){
            return kthsmallest(arr, low, pos-1, k);
    }

    return kthsmallest(arr, pos+1, high, k-(pos+1));

}
}
```

However it works when I change the last call in kthsmallest function i.e.

Change: `return kthsmallest(arr, pos+1, high, k-(pos+1));`

To: `return kthsmallest(arr, pos+1, high, k-(pos+1)+low);`

I want to understand why I need to add low to k-(pos+1). Because in my view, when we have the subarray on the right in which the recursion enters, the kth smallest number in the large array boils down to k - last partition element -1 i.e. k-(pos+1).

Comment: if k is small you can just keep a sub buffer, you can collect k elements in ~n time where quicksort is going to always be O(n log n)... I know it doesn't help your problem

Comment: I presume `k>0 & k<=high-low+1` is a typo and you intended `&&`? Also, where did this quickselect routine come from? Is this one you are inventing from scratch? I ask because it looks like you need to take it back to the drawing board. Remember, you do not need a sort, but just need to identify the partition containing the kth element. I suspect the lack of further comment or answers are due to a lot of head scratching trying to sort out just what you are trying to accomplish. Please post a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin QuickSelect? I dont have that referenced anywhere in the question. If you meant quicksort, then i have specified in the question itself that this is a variation of  the quicksort algorithm. And yes i don't need a sort, that is the reason the partitioning is based on 'k'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `low` because when you recursively start with a new array, `low` will be the reference for `pos`. So the new `k` will be calculated from `low` to `pos`.

Maybe an example would be more clarifying.

Lets find the 9th smallest element of this array:
[image: array]

Now we do the partition, so we get:
[image: partition1]

From `pos` to the left we've got the smallest elements in the array, that's the 3 smallest elements. Now we'll work with the subarray starting from `pos+1`. And we need to get the 6th smallest element:
[image: subarray1]

We do a partition over this subarray:
[image: partition2]

Remember that we are working over a subarray trying to find the 6th smallest element. In this case we separated the `(pos - low + 1)`th smallest elements in the subarray. So our new `k` will be:
[image: subarray2]
We do a new partition:
[image: partition3]
Now we exceeded the 4th smallest element of the last subarray, so we trim the last part:
[image: subarray3]
We do the partition again:
[image: partition4]

And we get:
[image: final]

So our number is `17`.

Hope it helps.

PD: As David C. Rankin says in comments you probably should change `&` for `&&`.

Answer (score 3):

It appears one of the problems you are having is trying to shoehorn a quickselect routine into a *recursive* function when there is *no reason* to make the function recursive to begin with. All you need to do is identify the partition the `'k'` element resides in, there is no need to sort. All you need for your `kthsmallest` is:

```
/** select the ZERO BASED 'k' element from 'arr'.
 *  where 'low' and 'high' are the ZERO BASED low
 *  and high indexes for 'arr'.
 */
int kthsmallest (int *arr, int low, int high, int k)
{
    for (;;) {
        if (low == high)
            return arr[low];

        int pos = partition (arr, low, high);

        if (k == pos)
            return arr[k];
        else if (k < pos)
            high = pos - 1;
        else
            low = pos + 1;
    }
}
```

Using your exact `partition` and `swap` functions, you can write a small example program to test `k` for every element in an array. (***note:*** the element returned is based on a ***zero indexed k***, e.g. the *first* smallest element is offset *zero* from the end of the array -- just like in the rest of C)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap (int *a, int *b);
int partition (int *arr, int l, int r);

/** select the ZERO BASED 'k' element from 'arr'.
 *  where 'low' and 'high' are the ZERO BASED low
 *  and high indexes for 'arr'.
 */
int kthsmallest (int *arr, int low, int high, int k)
{
    for (;;) {
        if (low == high)
            return arr[low];

        int pos = partition (arr, low, high);

        if (k == pos)
            return arr[k];
        else if (k < pos)
            high = pos - 1;
        else
            low = pos + 1;
    }
}

int main (void) {

    int a[] = { 51, 86, 34, 79, 92, 68, 14, 47, 22, 6 },
        nelem = sizeof a / sizeof *a;

    for (int i = 0; i < nelem; i++)
        printf (" nth (%2d) element is : %d\n", i,
                kthsmallest (a, 0, nelem - 1, i));

    return 0;
}

void swap (int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp = *b;
    *b = *a;
    *a = temp;
}

int partition (int *arr, int l, int r)
{
    int pivot = arr[r];
    int i = l, j = 0;

    for (j = l; j <= r - 1; j++) {
        if (arr[j] <= pivot) {
            swap (&arr[i], &arr[j]);
            i++;
        }
    }

    swap (&arr[i], &arr[j]);

    return i;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/kthsmall
 nth ( 0) element is : 6
 nth ( 1) element is : 14
 nth ( 2) element is : 22
 nth ( 3) element is : 34
 nth ( 4) element is : 47
 nth ( 5) element is : 51
 nth ( 6) element is : 68
 nth ( 7) element is : 79
 nth ( 8) element is : 86
 nth ( 9) element is : 92
```

Comment: How is your algorithm providing the right answer when pivot < k? Once you're in that subset of elements aren't you supposed to be looking for ```k - pivot``` smallest element?

Comment: Okay, I think you're bringing your low and high closer to each other until they find the right place, would you say this approach is faster or slower or roughly comparable to the idea of recursively eliminating some portion and looking for the solution in this new subproblem?